# Video uploading to firebase storage taking too long

Tags: android, performance, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using the below code snippet to uploading video to Firebase Storage.

```
file_path.putFile(selectedMediaUri).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    Integer uploaded = (int)taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred();
                    Integer total = (int)taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                    notificationBuilder.setProgress(total, uploaded, false);
                    notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notificationBuilder.build());

                }
            }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    notificationBuilder.setContentText("Your story is uploaded").setProgress(0,0,false);
                    notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notificationBuilder.build());

                }
            });
```

This code is working fine in uploading video to Firebase storage.
But I have two issues.

1. The video is taking too long while uploading to the storage. 2MB
   file took more than 1 minute.
2. `OnProgress` function update the notification very late. I want to update the notification (in `onProgress` function) every second. So that User can see the progress of uploading. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: you can use an AsyncTask with onprogressupdate and do the percentage with a progress bar

Comment: Main problem firebase function `OnProgress` respond back very late. How will I update the progress in `OnProgressUpdate` of `AsyncTask`?